# Toggle a Div container height

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on  a  button on which the toggle applies and the div height increases and decreases.
So what i am trying to do is that on a button lets say on `#about` click the `#aboutsubmenu` shows and the height of `#maincontainer` increases and on same click if if it's open it closes.
Here is what i am trying to do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#aboutsubmenu').hide();
    var opened;
    var opened2;
    $('#about').click(function() {
        opened = "no";
        if (opened == "no") {
            $('#aboutsubmenu').show();
            $('#maincontainer').css('height', '387px');
            opened = "yes";
        }
        else if (opened == "yes") {

        }
    });
});
```

**I am totally confused here. Can you help me out.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Initialize your variable outside event handler

```
var opened = "no"; //
var opened2;
$('#about').click(function () {
    if (opened == "no") {
        $('#aboutsubmenu').show();
        $('#maincontainer').css('height', '387px');
        opened = "yes";
    } else if (opened == "yes") {
        $('#aboutsubmenu').hide();
        $('#maincontainer').css('height', '100px');
        opened = "no";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#aboutsubmenu').hide();
    var opened = false;
    $('#about').click(function () {
        $('#aboutsubmenu').toggle(); // Toggle visibility
        $('#maincontainer').height(opened ? 387 : 100);
        opened = !opened;
    });
});
```

What you did wrong:

```
opened = "no";
```

that code at the start of the function makes it alwasy open.

Comment: *"on every click"* rather than *function start*

Comment: This will do the exact same thing as Satpal's awnser only shorter code.